# How to read expect output in bash variable?

Tags: bash, expect

I use expect tu verify a password against ssh.
I have tried to output via puts
but I just get the end of the server response in the string.

How do I only get the puts values?

```
okk=$(expect -c "
set timeout 15
spawn ssh -p 22 user@server.com 
expect {
    \"(yes/no)\" {
        sleep 1
        send \"yes\n\"
        exp_continue
    }
    \"(y/n)\" {
        sleep 1
        send \"y\n\"
        exp_continue
    }
    password {
        sleep 1
        send \"$sshpw\r\"
        exp_continue
    }
    Password {
        sleep 1
        send \"$sshpw\r\"
        exp_continue
    }
    \"Last login\" {
        puts \"yes\"
        exit 1
    }
    \"Permission denied\" {
        return \"no\" 
        exit 1
    }
    timeout {
        puts \"timeout\"
        exit 1
    }
    eof {
        puts \"error\"
    }
}
sleep 1
expect eof
")

echo $okk
```

onsectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat nis

Comment: You don't see the strings you `puts` in the variable at all? Or you see them but also see the server output? Are you sure you are hitting one of your `puts` cases?

Comment: What's the purpose of that heap of "latin" stuff at the end of the question? Most folks here aren't going to be able to understand it, and so it provides no useful additional information to your question or code. Are you just trying to make it look like a "better" question just by having more "words" in it?

Comment: stackoverflow didn't let me post my question because it didn't contain enough text. so I fed it lorem ipsum (which is a dummy text)

Answer (score 1):

Two changes are needed to filter out everything except the output of `puts`:

1. Use `spawn -noecho ssh -p 22 user@server.com`
2. Add `log_user 0` after `set timeout 15`

*WARNING: if you hit a case that does not print anything in the EXPECT world, you will get an empty string in the BASH world. So, take care of this!*